# Convert string into date format in python

Tags: python

I want to iterate through the dates in for loop. 
sample ddates : 
20170101 20170107

output should be : 
20170101 
20170102 
20170103 
20170104 
20170105 
20170106 
20170107

Comment: Wheres your code?

Comment: for i in range(20170101,20170107 ): print i

Comment: It is taking the dates as integer. I want to convert it to date format

Answer (score -1):

datetime.strptime is what you're looking for

```
start = 20170101
end = 20170107
dates = []
for i in range(start, end):
  dates.append(datetime.strptime(str(i), "%Y%m%d"))
```

dates will then have:

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 0, 0)]
```